# django activity stream, am I approaching it wrong?

Tags: python, django

I'm using django-activity-stream for following/unfollowing and displaying the followed/unfollowed contents. But as a noobie, the documentation seems to vague. If anyone can figure out what I did wrong, I would be really appreciated. Here's the documentation; https://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/actions.html

Here's the steps I took.

```
pip install django-activity-stream
```

then added actstream in my setting/and set the url for actstream.
for url I also included,

```
url(r'^unfollow/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/', 'main.views.unfollow_user', name='unfollow'),
    url(r'^follow/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/', 'main.views.follow_user', name='follow'),
```

then I created apps.py inside my main app folder.

from django.apps import AppConfig
from actstream import registry

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'subs'

    def ready(self):
        registry.register(get_user_model())
        registry.register(self.get_model('Category'))
```

I'm trying to follow Category model, and display what's inside the category.

Here's models.py

```
    from actstream import action
    class Category(models.Model): 
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        image = models.FileField(upload_to='images',blank=True, null=True)
        author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

        def __unicode__(self): 
            return self.name

    def new_category(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        action.send(instance.user, verb='posted', target=instance, mood='sleepy')

    post_save.connect(new_category, sender=Category)
```

Then in views.py, this is the part I'm shaky

```
def timeline(request):
    activities = user_stream(request.user)
    context = {
        'activities': activities,
    }
    return render(request, 'all_timeline.html', context)


def category_timeline(request, category_name):
    user = User.objects.select_related('profile').get(category_name=category_name)
    user_actions = []

    if is_following(request.user, user) or not user.profile.private:
        user_actions = actor_stream(user)

    context = {
        'user': user,
        'activities': user_actions,
    }
    return render(request, 'timeline.html', context)


def follow_user(request, category_name):
    follow(request.user, User.objects.get(category_name=category_name))
    return redirect('category_timeline', category_name)


def unfollow_user(request, category_name):
    unfollow(request.user, User.objects.get(category_name=category_name))
    return redirect('category_timeline', category_name)
```

In the tutorial, they were using user_name but since I'm following category i figured I have to change it to category_name...which could mess things up with the original actstream app maybe?
\Here if I just want the functionality the contents from following category to be displayed then I don't need timeline function right?

In short, when I go into follow/url I get `follow_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_name_url' and it's occuring from env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 132` so I have no idea what's occuring. Also not sure what I'm doing...
This is my traceback

```
env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /follow/aa/
Exception Value: follow_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_name_url'
```

Comment: You have a variable name mismatch. The views require `caregory_name` while the url rule captures `category_name_url`. Change one of them!

Comment: @KlausD. thank you but if I change unify the variables with category_name_url I get FieldError at /follow/aa/
Cannot resolve keyword 'category_name_url' into field. Choices are: api_key, category so I changed all of them to category. Then I get the same error I got: follow_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_name_url'

Comment: Did you change the name of the capture group in the regex as well?

Comment: thanks for the reply, currently I have     url(r'^follow/(?P<category>\w+)/', 'main.views.follow_user', name='follow'), and unified the variables to category. but with this, my worry is that I have  url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
and this is the one users can follow. Also now I get invalid literal for int() with base 10: from      follow(request.user, User.objects.get(category=category))

Comment: There are some problems in you code. Try to change the query parameter to `category__name=` with two underscores. It that does not help, upadte your code and error message by editing the question.

Comment: I agree there are many problems, It's my first time using django-activity-stream. I have created new question;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916046/invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-aa-im-not-trying-to-pass-number-why

Comment: Mr Klaus D, can you please help me with this app through chat?