# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'aa',,I'm not trying to pass number why am I getting this?

Tags: python, django

Hello I'm django activity stream, and I got this error: invalid literal for int() with base 10 when I tried to follow category named aa. This is my code

```
def category_timeline(request, category):
    user = User.objects.select_related('profile').get(category=category)
    user_actions = []

    if is_following(request.user, user) or not user.profile.private:
        user_actions = actor_stream(user)

    context = {
        'user': user,
        'activities': user_actions,
    }
    return render(request, 'timeline.html', context)


def follow_user(request, category):
    follow(request.user, User.objects.get(category=category))
    return redirect('category_timeline', category)

def unfollow_user(request, category):
    unfollow(request.user, User.objects.get(category=category))
    return redirect('category_timeline', category)
```

Here's my traceback

It's occuring from here `user = User.objects.select_related('profile').get(category=category)`
 I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. What I'm trying to do is to display the users to be able to follow categories, and display the contents of the category.
I have category model and category view 
it looks like this

```
def category(request, category_name_url):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    category_name = decode_url(category_name_url)


    category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
```

Traceback:

```
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "rclone/main/views.py" in follow_user
  271.     follow(request.user, User.objects.get(category=category))
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  325.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  679.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  697.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1309.         clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1337.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1199.                                                     lookups, value)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in get_lookup_constraint
  1751.                     lookup_class(target.get_col(alias, source), val), AND)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in __init__
  101.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  139.         return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  727.             return self.get_prep_value(value)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  985.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /follow/
```

Comment: Looks like one of the fields in `profile` model is defined integer and database is returning 'aa' for that.

Comment: @shreyas, thanks for the advise but I don't have profile model or any model field that's defined integer....not sure how this django-activity-stream works but...I don't have any int field but I get this error...

Comment: I am talking about this line `User.objects.select_related('profile').get(category=category)`. `profile` is a proxy name to the custom model for extending `User` model. can you verify which model is that?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm following on django-activity-stream and just followed that code blindly without realizing the 'profile' needs to be category since I have category model that needs to be followed by user. but even after I switch to category, I get same error....I'm just trying to use activity stream but this seems too advance for me....can you please help me out?

Comment: can you you point me to docs that you are following?

Comment: yes of course, the documentation is here https://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html and my friend provided me this to follow https://github.com/mauler/activity-stream

Comment: @shreyas thank you for taking a look at this, this app looks awesome and it  fits my requirement which is to allow users to follow categories and see the contents inside that followed categories

Comment: this https://github.com/mauler/activity-stream/blob/master/subs/models.py has `Profile` model, do you have the same model?

Comment: In fact; can I see your model file?

Comment: Yes I have category model, https://github.com/lip365/ebagu0.2/blob/master/rclone/main/models.py

Comment: sorry readability for this code is really bad...this is my first django project I have java background mostly..my first web proj

Comment: You should create a `Profile` model same as in https://github.com/mauler/activity-stream/blob/master/subs/models.py, and use the exact line `user = User.objects.select_related('profile').get(username=username)` in code

Comment: thank you I will defitiely try this right now

Comment: @shreyas I'm also using userena app so I have myProfile model here https://github.com/lip365/ebagu0.2/blob/cea4db1323f95c83f464f7a352ee488e679f4a67/rclone/accounts/models.py, should I change this to Profile?

Comment: thanks but  I still get the same error

Comment: You have profile model already, this is what I was talking about. So you don't need to add new `Profile` model. Based on `MyProfile` model you need to use this in your code `User.objects.select_related('my_profile').get(username=username)`. Make sure you derive username from logged in user. I hope this works

Comment: let me know if that works I will post summarized answer

Comment: it still gives me the same error, I think the problem is follow(request.user, User.objects.get(category=category))  line

Comment: @shreyas can you help me through a chat?

Comment: can you try this one more thing? first fetch category from db and pass category.id in argument. `cat_obj = Category.objects.get(name=category)` something like that. and then, ` follow(request.user, User.objects.get(category=cat_obj.id))`

Comment: @shreyas thank you I think that's the way to go, can you post that as an answer so I can switch what I need to and check that as an answer?

Comment: awesome, I will post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the final conclusion from above discussion

in this call `User.objects.get(category=category))` it is expecting primary key of Category model instead of a string.

So something like following should work

```
category_id = Category.objects.get(name=category)
User.objects.get(category=category_id))
```